# Plotting ROC & AUC for SVM algorithm

Tags: python, svm, anomaly-detection, auc

Towards , the end of my program, I have the following code.

```
model = svm.OneClassSVM(nu=nu, kernel='rbf', gamma=0.00001) 
model.fit(train_data)
```

Output

```
OneClassSVM(cache_size=200, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=1e-05, kernel='rbf',
            max_iter=-1, nu=0.0031259768677711786, random_state=None,
            shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

```
from sklearn import metrics
preds = model.predict(train_data)
targs = train_target 
print("accuracy: ", metrics.accuracy_score(targs, preds))
print("precision: ", metrics.precision_score(targs, preds)) 
print("recall: ", metrics.recall_score(targs, preds))
print("f1: ", metrics.f1_score(targs, preds))
print("area under curve (auc): ", metrics.roc_auc_score(targs, preds))
train_preds = preds
```

output

```
accuracy:  0.9050484526414505
precision:  0.9974137931034482
recall:  0.907095256762054
f1:  0.9501129131595154
area under curve (auc):  0.5876939698444417
```

```
preds = model.predict(test_data)
targs = test_target 
print("accuracy: ", metrics.accuracy_score(targs, preds))
print("precision: ", metrics.precision_score(targs, preds)) 
print("recall: ", metrics.recall_score(targs, preds))
print("f1: ", metrics.f1_score(targs, preds))
print("area under curve (auc): ", metrics.roc_auc_score(targs, preds))
test_preds = preds
```

output

```
accuracy:  0.9043451078462019
precision:  1.0
recall:  0.9040752351097179
f1:  0.9496213368455713
area under curve (auc):  0.9520376175548589
```

I am having trouble plotting the ROC & AUC . On my side I’ve been trying to read articles and check but unsuccessful until. The fact that I am only working with one column might be the cause.

Answer (score 2):

The ROC curve requires probability estimates (or at least a realistic rank-ordering), which one-class SVM doesn't really try to produce.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/99179/232706
https://stackoverflow.com/q/41266389/10495893
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14685318/10495893
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/993

When you call `roc_auc_score` on the results of `predict`, you're generating an ROC curve with only three points: the lower-left, the upper-right, and a single point representing the model's decision function.  This may be useful, but it isn't a traditional auROC.

Finally, note the end of https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html#overview-of-outlier-detection-methods :

> The `svm.OneClassSVM` is known to be sensitive to outliers and thus does not perform very well for outlier detection.

This method is better suited to novelty detection than outlier detection.  By training on some of the outliers, you've told the model that those are "normal" points.

Comment: Right, an ROC plots classifier performance over the entire range of possible decision thresholds. If you have only class labels and not some kind of continuous class "score", you've effectively already set the decision threshold. I'd say an ROC in this case isn't very useful at all - you're just showing the performance of your one single classifier, alongside the degenerate cases of all positive/negative predictions. You'd be better off just describing metrics of the already-thersholded classifier by itself. ROC doesn't make much sense when there is only 1 classification threshold to examine.

Comment: @Ben Reiniger, my problem is that I am not even able to print that graph that based on your answer it is not even a traditional auROC The entire idea behind this is to check how the algorithm performs when I use different ranges of anomalies when I switch the training to testing ranges of data So at the end I have it graphically shown how they performed

Comment: What have you tried?  What goes wrong when trying to plot the ROC curve?  (But I'll reiterate, the plot won't be any more informative than the specificity and sensitivity of the hard classification.)

Answer (score 2):

## If you are performing a binary classification task then the following code might help you.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
```

for hyper-parameter tuning.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
```

by default, it fits a linear support vector machine (SVM)

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
```

The function roc_curve computes the receiver operating characteristic curve or ROC curve.

```
model = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge',alpha = alpha_hyperparameter_bow,penalty=penalty_hyperparameter_bow,class_weight='balanced')
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
# roc_auc_score(y_true, y_score) the 2nd parameter should be probability estimates of the positive class, not the predicted outputs.

y_train_pred = model.decision_function(x_train)    
y_test_pred = model.decision_function(x_test)
```

The former, decision_function, finds the distance to the separating hyperplane. For example, a(n) SVM classifier finds hyperplanes separating the space into areas associated with classification outcomes. This function, given a point, finds the distance to the separators. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543137/whats-the-difference-between-predict-proba-and-decision-function-in-scikit-lear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZH1k.png)

```
train_fpr, train_tpr, tr_thresholds = roc_curve(y_train, y_train_pred)
test_fpr, test_tpr, te_thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_test_pred)

plt.grid()

plt.plot(train_fpr, train_tpr, label=" AUC TRAIN ="+str(auc(train_fpr, train_tpr)))
plt.plot(test_fpr, test_tpr, label=" AUC TEST ="+str(auc(test_fpr, test_tpr)))
plt.plot([0,1],[0,1],'g--')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("False Positive Rate")
plt.ylabel("True Positive Rate")
plt.title("AUC(ROC curve)")
plt.grid(color='black', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: Code output]